# Is fail2ban regex standard?

Tags: regex, fail2ban

I have a log entry:

```
[22-May-2021 08:36:01 Europe/London] 10.0.0.2 - Failed admin login attempt for root at http://www.example.com:80
```

that I'm trying to be matched by a `fail2ban` configuration.

I test it at a [regex tester](https://www.regextester.com/97589) and I can see the `^\[.*?\].* - Failed admin login attempt for .*` pattern matches fine.

But somehow `fail2ban` does not match it:

```
fail2ban-regex php_error_log "^\[.*?\].* - Failed admin login attempt for .*"
```

It shows:

```
Use   failregex line : ^\[.*?\].* - Failed admin login attempt for .*
ERROR: No failure-id group in '^\[.*?\].* - Failed admin login attempt for .*'
```

Comment: my named gets spammed so i had a similar idea 
log:
`May 22 12:37:02 pve named[27393]: client @0x7fd2204c0420 128.116.5.164#61240 (.): rate limit drop all response to 128.116.0.0/20`

fail2ban 
`failregex = ^\s*\S+\s+named(?:\[\d+\])?: client (?:@0x\S+ )?<ADDR>[^:]*: rate limit drop all response`


in fact it is not easy to have a valid fail regex

Comment: what I miss in your regex is the variable `<addr>`